# Adjoint of Matrices Defined by Inner Products

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let *H* be a Hilbert space and let $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal basis for *H*. Now define for each $T \in {\bf B}(H)$ the doubly infinite matrix $A = (\alpha_{nm})$ by setting $\alpha_{nm} = (Te_n|e_m)$. I am trying to find the matrix corresponding to $T^*$.

I know that since $T^*$ is the adjoint of *T* that for every $x,y \in H$,
\begin{align*}
(Tx|y) = (x|T^*y).
\end{align*}
Furthermore, since $(e_n)$ forms a basis for *H*, it suffices to show that
\begin{align*}
(Te_n|e_m) = (e_n|T^*e_m).
\end{align*}
So I expressed $Te_n = \alpha_{1n}e_1 + \cdots$ and observed that since $(e_n)$ is an orthonormal that
\begin{align*}
(Te_n|e_m) = \alpha_{mn}(e_m|e_m) = \alpha_{mn} = (Te_m|e_n).
\end{align*}
However, I could not see how to relate this to $(e_n|T^*e_m)$.

Also, it seems there is almost a canonical way to defined the matrix corresponding to $T^*$, however, I am not sure how to do it.

Any help or direction would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The corresponding matrix for $T^*$ is the (conjugate, if complex) transpose of the matrix for $T$. This is because $(Te_n \mid e_m) = \overline{(T^* e_m \mid e_n)}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\langle T^*e_n, e_m\rangle = \langle e_n, Te_m\rangle = \overline{\langle Te_m, e_n\rangle } = \overline{\alpha_{mn}}$$